# SaveAll not saving associated hasOne data

Tags: php, cakephp

Been at this one for a few hours and can't figure out why this is happening, any assistance appreciated...

I have two models - Images & Links.

Images `hasOne` Links

Links `belongsTo` Images

I am putting together data in the following format into a var called `$images`

```
Array
(
    Array
    (
        [Image] => Array
            (
                [timestamp] => ...
                [full] => ...
            )

        [Link] => Array
            (
                [loc] => ...
                [lastmod] => ...
            )

    )
    ...
)
```

Then calling `$this->Image->saveAll($images, array('deep'=>true));`

This saves the Image model, but it is not saving the Link model.

In beforeSave callback for the Image model, the data in $this->data is being passed appropriately.  But in the afterSave callback , the Link model is showing up - BUT its fields are empty.

No data is being saved to MySQL for the Link data, only the Image data.

Am I missing something?  Been through the docs a million times :(

Comment: Could you post your `$hasOne` and `$belongsTo` in your models?

Answer (score 2):

I feel kinda stupid answering this, but here it goes.

I was using some debug code in `afterSave()` for the `Image` model.

After printing out the data and what not, I called `exit()`.

I was oblivious to the fact that, after saving `Image`, CakePHP was not going to get to the `Link` model in the data to save that too.

0_0